# Check if custom List contains an Item

Tags: java

I've got an custom List and want to check if it contains a special Item. TheList is populated with `Rowlayout` objects.

```
public RowLayout(String content, int number) {
        this.content = content;
        this.number = number;
    }
```

Now i wanna check if my `List<Roalayout>` contains a special item at the `content` - position. How do I do that?

It doesn't work with just asking `.contains'`.

**What i wanna check:**

```
if (!List<RowLayout>.contains("insert here"){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: `hashCode` and `equals` do the magic ;)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy unless you can't change the class code...

Comment: do you have java-8?

Comment: @Eugene in that case using a `Map` might be a better decision than using a `List`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filtering an ArrayList using an object's field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856554/filtering-an-arraylist-using-an-objects-field)

Comment: Show your code, or edit your question so we can understand it properly

Comment: Ye, I have Java 8. And how do `hashcode` and `equals` do the magic? :DD

Comment: @Sarius if you don't use `@` in front of someones name - there is no way I know you actually replied...

Answer (score 7):

If you can edit the class `RowLayout` just override `hashCode` and `equals` with whatever equality you want for them.

If you can't and have java-8 for example, this could be done:

```
String content = ...
int number = ...

boolean isContained = yourList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getContent().equals(content))   
        .filter(x -> x.getNumber() == number)
        .findAny()
        .isPresent();
```

You can obviously return the instance you are interested in from that `Optional` from `findAny`.

Comment: Sorry, but im a total beginner. What do you mean by "just override `hashCode` and `equals`"?

Comment: @Sarius https://www.google.com/search?q=java+override+hashcode+and+equals&rlz=1C5CHFA_enMD720MD720&oq=java+override+hashcode+&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j69i60j0l4.6046j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

You just need to override `equals` for [`List.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) to work accordingly. `List.contains` says in the documentation:

> Returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e
>   such that
> (o==null ? e==null : **o.equals(e)**).

Your implementation of `equals` may look like this:

```
class RowLayout {
    private String content;
    private int number;

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (!(o instanceof RowLayout)) return false;
        final RowLayout that = (RowLayout) o;
        return this.content.equals(that.content) && this.number == that.number;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [also override `hashCode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java), else your class will not work in hash-based structures like `HashSet`s or `HashMap`s.

Example usage:

```
myList.contains(new RowLayout("Hello", 99));
```

---

An alternative Java 8 solution if you only care about the content and don't care about the number would be to do this:

```
boolean isContained = myList.stream() 
                            .map(RowLayout::getContent)
                            .anyMatch("some content");
```

Comment: And i when I just wanna chekc if it contains an Item at just the first position? F.e. `myList.contains(new RowLayout("Hello"));`

Comment: Thank you for being that honest!

Comment: @Sarius No problem. I've added another Java 8 solution which is shorter if you only care about a single field.