# Get count of items in ArrayList based on property on type

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a count of how many Items are of itemTypeId 1

**Item**

```
public class Item {
  private int itemTypeId;

  public int getItemTypeId() {
    return this.itemTypeId;
  }
}
```

So for example lets say we have 4 instances of the above.  2 of them have an itemTypeId of 1.  Then and we add them to an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new Array<>();
items.push(item1);
items.push(item2);
items.push(item3);
items.push(item4);
```

I need to get the count of how many items have an itemTypeId of 1:

```
Integer quantityOfTypeOne = ???
```

This did not work, it says `equals()` is not a method it recognizes

```
Integer quantityOfTypeOne = items.stream().filter(item -> item.getItemTypeId().equals(1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and I tried `==` which I think is not a good way to compare integers anyway:

```
Integer quantityOfTypeOne = items.stream().filter(item -> item.getItemTypeId() == 1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16856554/10740241 

I guess the answers in this link might help

Comment: Also, if you just want the count, the variable should be `int`. Integer is the wrapper class. `int` is enough for the purpose

Comment: no I'm asking for a specific filtered count, only those items with an itemTypeId of 1

Comment: there has got to be an easier way than that huge stream expression or creating predicates.  You're telling me Java doesn't have something like JS does with filter?

Comment: stream and filter seems to be what most say. There is also the removeIf, which you mostly would have seen, but that seems to be worse as it modifies the list.

Comment: @PositiveGuy JS filter _also_ requires a predicate; in the very basic JS type system, it's called "function whose return value is truthy or falsy".

Answer (score 1):

Please use `==` for comparing primitive integers.

```
int quantityOfTypeOne  = items.stream().filter(item -> item.getItemTypeId()==1).collect(Collectors.toList()).size();
```

Learn more about [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You said you only want the count, so a simple reducing stream is idiomatic:

```java
items.stream()
  .mapToInt(Item::getItemTypeId)
  .filter(id -> id == 1)
  .count()
```

Comment: Need to typecast this to int. Got an error `"incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int"`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working even simpler with:

```
items.stream().filter(item -> item.getItemTypeId() == 1).count()
```